# EntityFrameworkCore throws NullReferenceException when querying data

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, oracle11g, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 2.2 to connect to an Oracle11g database (using these old versions is a must), when I try to query one of my tables it throws a `NullReferenceException` in the EF Core external code.
The Query:

```
string username = "Administrator";
var user = _context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName.ToUpper() == username.ToUpper())
                    .Include(x => x.UserProfile)
                    .Include(x => x.UserRoleOrganizations).ThenInclude(s => s.Role)
                    .Include(x => x.UserRoleOrganizations).ThenInclude(s => s.Organization);

return user.FirstOrDefault();
```

The exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.CreateGetValueExpression(Expression dataReaderExpression, Int32 index, TypeMaterializationInfo materializationInfo, Boolean detailedErrorsEnabled, Boolean box)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<CreateArrayInitializer>b__0(TypeMaterializationInfo mi, Int32 i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__5`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.CollectionExtensions.ToReadOnly[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NewArrayInit(Type type, IEnumerable`1 initializers)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.CreateArrayInitializer(CacheKey cacheKey, Boolean detailedErrorsEnabled)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.<Create>b__11_0(CacheKey k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ResultEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass15_1`1.<CompileQueryCore>b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at Base.Security.Business.UserManagement.GetUser(String username) in C:\Users\Afagh2\source\repos\HSE2_Oracle\Base.Security\Business\UserManagement.cs:line 88
```

The generated query:

```
[Parameters=[:ToUpper_0='ADMINISTRATOR' (Size = 256)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='0']
Select
K0 "Id", K1 "AccessFailedCount", K2 "ConcurrencyStamp", K3 "Email", K4 "EmailConfirmed", K5 "FirstName", K6 "IsActive", K7 "IsExternal", K8 "LastName", K9 "LockoutEnabled", K10 "LockoutEnd", K11 "NationalCode", K12 "NormalizedEmail", K13 "NormalizedUserName", K14 "OrganizationName", K15 "OrganizationType", K16 "PasswordHash", K17 "PersonnelCode", K18 "PhoneNumber", K19 "PhoneNumberConfirmed", K20 "PositionName", K21 "SecurityStamp", K22 "TwoFactorEnabled", K23 "UserName", K24 "Id", K25 "FileContent", K26 "FileExtension", K27 "FileName" from(
  SELECT "x"."Id" K0, "x"."AccessFailedCount" K1, "x"."ConcurrencyStamp" K2, "x"."Email" K3, "x"."EmailConfirmed" K4, "x"."FirstName" K5, "x"."IsActive" K6, "x"."IsExternal" K7, "x"."LastName" K8, "x"."LockoutEnabled" K9, "x"."LockoutEnd" K10, "x"."NationalCode" K11, "x"."NormalizedEmail" K12, "x"."NormalizedUserName" K13, "x"."OrganizationName" K14, "x"."OrganizationType" K15, "x"."PasswordHash" K16, "x"."PersonnelCode" K17, "x"."PhoneNumber" K18, "x"."PhoneNumberConfirmed" K19, "x"."PositionName" K20, "x"."SecurityStamp" K21, "x"."TwoFactorEnabled" K22, "x"."UserName" K23, "x.UserProfile"."Id" K24, "x.UserProfile"."FileContent" K25, "x.UserProfile"."FileExtension" K26, "x.UserProfile"."FileName" K27
  FROM "AppUser" "x"
  LEFT JOIN "AppUserProfilePicture" "x.UserProfile" ON ("x"."Id" = "x.UserProfile"."Id")
  WHERE ("UPPER"("x"."UserName") = :ToUpper_0)
  ORDER BY "x"."Id"
) "m1"
where rownum <= 1
```

The query works as expected in Oracle SQL Developer. It seems that EF Core has some trouble converting the results to the entity (which in this case, the result should be none because the table has no data.) but I can not debug its code. (Or can I?)
The entity is configured in `OnModelCreating`:

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
{
    b.HasKey(u => u.Id);
    b.HasIndex(u => u.NormalizedUserName).HasName("UserNameIndex").IsUnique();
    b.HasIndex(u => u.NormalizedEmail).HasName("EmailIndex");
    b.ToTable("AppUser");
    b.Property(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp).IsConcurrencyToken();

    b.Property(u => u.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);
    b.Property(u => u.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);
    b.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(256);
    b.Property(u => u.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);

    b.HasOne(x => x.UserProfile).WithOne(x => x.User).HasForeignKey<ApplicationUserProfilePicture>(x => x.Id);
    b.HasMany<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().WithOne().HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId).IsRequired();
    b.HasMany<IdentityUserLogin<int>>().WithOne().HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId).IsRequired();
    b.HasMany<IdentityUserToken<int>>().WithOne().HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId).IsRequired();
    b.HasMany<ApplicationUserRoleOrganization>().WithOne().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId).IsRequired();
});
```

I can create and query other tables. Only `AppUser` table doesn't work in Oracle, it works fine using the SQL Server provider.
Tell me if more info about anything is needed.

---

**Update**
User class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string PositionName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string NationalCode { get; set; }
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string PersonnelCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsExternal { get; set; } = false;
    [Required]
    public OrganizationTypeEnum OrganizationType { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUserProfilePicture UserProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRoleOrganization> UserRoleOrganizations { get; set; }
}
```

UserRoleOrganization class:

```
public class ApplicationUserRoleOrganization : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserRole<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override int RoleId { get => base.RoleId; set => base.RoleId = value; }
    public override int UserId { get => base.UserId; set => base.UserId = value; }
    public virtual int OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration of UserRoleOrganization:

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRoleOrganization>(b =>
{
    b.HasKey(r => r.Id);
    b.HasIndex(t => t.OrganizationId).HasName("OrganizationIndex");
    b.HasIndex(t => t.RoleId).HasName("RoleIndex");
    b.HasIndex(t => t.UserId).HasName("UserIndex");
    b.HasOne(userRole => userRole.Role)
    .WithMany(role => role.UserRoleOrganizations)
    .HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.RoleId).HasConstraintName("FK_RoleOrg_Role_RoleId");
    b.HasOne(userRole => userRole.Organization)
    .WithMany(role => role.UserRoleOrganizations)
    .HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.OrganizationId).HasConstraintName("FK_RoleOrg_Org_OrgId");
    b.HasOne(userRole => userRole.User)
    .WithMany(user => user.UserRoleOrganizations)
    .HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.UserId).HasConstraintName("FK_RoleOrg_User_UserId");
    b.ToTable("AppUserRoleOrganization");
});
```

---

I just noticed a text is written in my output just before the exception:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Base.Security.Data.SecurityDbContext'.
```

Comment: first, are you sure the exception is thrown from the query you posted? try removing parts of that query until it becomes the simplest form (e.g: `_context.Users`) to find out what could cause the exception (that's how we solve the issue ourselves, a very well-known method called `trial and error`). That could save you a question posted in SO or could at least provide us with more valuable info. Second, can you easily reproduce the error, is there any threading involved?

Comment: I sure do test the simple query before asking such a big and specific question in SO. Even `_context.Users.ToList()` will fail. And for the second part, I don't understand why I should reproduce the error as it's always there.

Comment: if `_context.Users.ToList()` is failed as well, it should have been the query you asked about because it's much simpler so we can focus on other possibilities instead of focusing on the detailed query itself. You should then try getting other db sets on that `_context` to see if the error is thrown as well. BTW this seem to be very strange because the `_context.Users.ToList()` is just so simple that there would be something wrong ***elsewhere*** rather in the query. That kind of `NullReferenceException` also does not make much sense in this case, making it even harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have included UserRoleOrganizations twice . Try to do including the good old way:

```
string username = "Administrator";
return _context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName.ToUpper() == username.ToUpper())
                    .Include(x => x.UserProfile)
                    .Include("UserRoleOrganizations.Organization");
                    .Include("UserRoleOrganizations.Role")
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But I don't like UserRoleOrganizations.Organization . Could you please show your User and UserRoleOrganizations clases?

Update.

Since I can see the classes, I think you can try to reverse query, maybe just for testing:

```
var userRoleOrganizations=_context.UserRoleOrganizations
.Where(x => x.User.UserName.ToUpper() == username.ToUpper())
.Include(s => s.Role)
.Include(s => s.Organization)
.ToList();

var user = _context.Users
.Where(x => x.UserName.ToUpper() == username.ToUpper())
.Include(x => x.UserProfile)
.FirstOrDefault();

user.UserRoleOrganizations=userRoleOrganizations;

return user;
```

And try to change the UserRoleOrganizations class:

```
public class UserRoleOrganizations
{
....
public  override int? RoleId { get => base.RoleId; set => base.RoleId = value; }
 public override int? UserId { get => base.UserId; set => base.UserId = value; }
 public virtual int? OrganizationId { get; set; }
....
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with including a table twice, you saw the generated query is correct and simple. Even `_context.Users.ToList()` will fail with this table throwing the same exception. Everything that I try to do to this table will fail (except of creating it). I updated the question to provide the info you asked.

Comment: Thank you. But I still can't see the User class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the query still throws NRE. Changing UserRoleOrganizations didn't help too. Even if the first method would help, the Identity library (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager) has a method called CreateAsync used for creating a user, which runs the query on `AppUser` table to check if the username exists, thus I'll be still getting NRE and cannot reverse query.